# Lumen: Class Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, middleware, lumen

I'm new to Lumen and i am trying to setup authentification using OAuth2 with [this tutorial](http://esbenp.github.io/2015/05/26/lumen-web-api-oauth-2-authentication/)
when i try to access any route i got this error:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 738:
Class Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse does not exist

in Container.php line 738
at ReflectionClass->__construct('Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse') in Container.php line 738
at Container->build('Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse', array()) in Container.php line 633
at Container->make('Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse', array()) in Application.php line 205
at Application->make('Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse') in Pipeline.php line 123
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Laravel\Lumen\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in OAuthExceptionHandlerMiddleware.php line 36
at OAuthExceptionHandlerMiddleware->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(OAuthExceptionHandlerMiddleware), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Laravel\Lumen\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in RoutesRequests.php line 626
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array('LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Middleware\OAuthExceptionHandlerMiddleware', 'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse'), object(Closure)) in RoutesRequests.php line 382
at Application->dispatch(object(Request)) in RoutesRequests.php line 327
at Application->run(object(Request)) in index.php line 28
```

bootstrap\app.php

```
$app->middleware([
    'LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Middleware\OAuthExceptionHandlerMiddleware',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse'  // <--- added
]);

$app->routeMiddleware([
    'check-authorization-params' => 'Optimus\OAuth2Server\Middleware\CheckAuthCodeRequestMiddleware',
    'csrf' => 'Laravel\Lumen\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
    'oauth' => 'Optimus\OAuth2Server\Middleware\OAuthMiddleware',
    'oauth-owner' => 'Optimus\OAuth2Server\Middleware\OAuthOwnerMiddleware'
]);

$app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);
$app->register('LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Storage\FluentStorageServiceProvider');
$app->register('Optimus\OAuth2Server\OAuth2ServerServiceProvider');
```

routes.php

```
$app->group(['prefix' => 'v1','namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function($app)
{
    $app->get('post','PostController@index');
}
```

Comment: Have you installed `illuminate/cookie` package?

Answer (score 4):

Just run

> composer require illuminate/cookie

Then add this code at bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->singleton('cookie', function () use ($app) {
    return $app->loadComponent('session', 'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider', 'cookie');
});

$app->bind('Illuminate\Contracts\Cookie\QueueingFactory', 'cookie');
```

ref https://github.com/esbenp/lumen-api-oauth/issues/23