# Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ &lt;required&gt; $app ]] Lumen session

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm attempting to use Lumen session and cookie and it says [here](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.1/session) that

> To enable sessions, you must uncomment all of the middleware within
>   the $app->middleware() method call in your bootstrap/app.php file.

which I did

[image]

now it gives me this errorr

> Lumen: Class Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse
>   does not exist

so as told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36642933/lumen-class-illuminate-cookie-middleware-addqueuedcookiestoresponse-does-not-ex), I did..

> composer require illuminate/cookie

then add this to my `bootstrap/app.php`

```
$app->singleton('cookie', function () use ($app) {
    return $app->loadComponent('session', 'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider', 'cookie');
});

$app->bind('Illuminate\Contracts\Cookie\QueueingFactory', 'cookie');
```

then run again, then gives me

> No application encryption key has been specified.

so since Lumen unable to do `php artisan key:generate` which i think only available on Laravel so I grab an `APP_KEY` from one of my Laravel projects then put it unto my lumen `.env` file

> APP_KEY=base64:RjLhaOy8c54rE189sa9Ts+oXSkL2xCJ22MjgRLdqz6g=

run and it gives me this error

> Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required>
>   $app ]] in class Illuminate\Support\Manager

any help, ideas please? I just want to use Lumen session and cookie feature why so complicated?

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a sample git repo with which I can reproduce this issue? At first glance i've got no clue, but then i can delve into it a bit deeper

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score -1):

you can add this code in your `bootstrap/app.php`:

```
$app->bind Illuminate\Support\Manager::class,function ($app) {
    return new \Illuminate\Support\Manager($app);
});
```